# Merging every other row in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking for a way to merge every other row in an excel file. So the data looks like this:

data 1 | data 2 | data 3|
data 4 | data 5 | data 6|
data 7 | data 8 | data 9|
data 10 | data 11 | data 12|

I want:

data 1 data 4 | data 2 data 5| data 3 data 6 |
data 7 data 10 | data 8 data 11| data 9 data 12|

I tried

=OFFSET(A$1,(ROW()-1)*2,0)&" "&OFFSET(A$1,((ROW()-1)*2)+1,0) A3

From documentation but doesn't seem to work.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would say this question should rather be posted in superuser.com
Anyways, you could paste this in the Visual Basic Editor, just replace the ranges.

```
Sub merge()

For Each cell In Range("A2: D2")
    cell.Offset(2, 0).Value = cell.Value & " " & cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
Next cell

End Sub
```